# If I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS when accessing my view from a delegate, does that mean I have a memory leak?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an object that I *init* like so:

```
pdtd = [[ProfileDataTableDelegate alloc] initWithTableView:profileDataTableView scrollView:contentScrollView];
```

so my `view` is passed to the `pdtd` object. I can log *my view* out at this point with no problem. I get the *error* when I click inside a text field and the scroll view is told to reposition. It's on my table delegate (pdtd) that I get the error which gives me "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" in the first line of this function:

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notif {
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 100) animated:YES]; // <-- ERROR SHOWS UP HERE

    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake([self.scrollView frame].size.width, 
                                               [self.scrollView frame].size.height + 100)];
}
```

Which is weird because I'm doing this on another view and it works fine. I'm not sure what's wrong or how to get more info from the debugger. Below are related functions from the associated classes.

## ProfileViewController.h

```
...

#import "ProfileDataTableDelegate.h"


@interface ProfileViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
    UITableView *profileDataTableView;
    ProfileDataTableDelegate *pdtd;
    UINavigationBar *navBar;
    UIScrollView *contentScrollView;
}

...

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *profileDataTableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ProfileDataTableDelegate *pdtd;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navBar;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *contentScrollView;

@end
```

## ProfileViewController.m

```
...

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //nav title
    [navBar.topItem setTitle:@"Your Profile"];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];

    // nav bar button
    UIBarButtonItem *saveButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(saveBtnTouched:)];
    saveButton.enabled = false;
    [navBar.topItem setRightBarButtonItem:saveButton];

    pdtd = [[ProfileDataTableDelegate alloc] initWithTableView:profileDataTableView scrollView:contentScrollView];

    void (^block)(BOOL) = ^(BOOL is_valid) {
        if(is_valid == YES) {
            [saveButton setEnabled:YES];
        } else if(is_valid == NO) {
            [saveButton setEnabled:NO];
        }
    };

    [pdtd setValidatorBlock:block];
}

...
```

## ProfileDateTableDelegate.h

```
...

#import "ValidatedTextViewTableCell.h"

typedef void (^ ValidatorBlock)(BOOL);

@interface ProfileDataTableDelegate : NSObject <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate> {
    UITableView *profileDataTableView;
    UIScrollView *scrollView;

        ...
}

- (id)initWithTableView:(UITableView *)tableView scrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;

...

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *profileDataTableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *scrollView;

@end
```

## ProfileDateTableDelegate.m

```
...

@implementation ProfileDataTableDelegate

@synthesize profileDataTableView;
@synthesize profileDataTableLabels;
@synthesize scrollView;

@synthesize emailCell, phoneCell, nameCell;
@synthesize validatedTextViewTableCell;
@synthesize validatorBlock;


- (id)initWithTableView:(UITableView *)tableView scrollView:(UIScrollView *)view {
    self = [super init];

    if(self) {
        profileDataTableView = tableView;
        [profileDataTableView setDelegate:self];
        [profileDataTableView setDataSource:self];

        scrollView = view;

        profileDataTableLabels = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Name", @"Email", @"Phone", nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector (keyboardDidShow:)
                                                     name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                 selector:@selector (keyboardDidHide:)
                                                     name: UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
    }

    return self;
}

...

- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notif {
    //NSLog(@"keyboard did show %@", notif); // notif gives coordinates etc
    //[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 480 - 372) animated:YES];

    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 100) animated:YES];

    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake([self.scrollView frame].size.width, 
                                               [self.scrollView frame].size.height + 100)];

    //[scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];


    // disable scrolling because it resets the rect position
    //[scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];
}

...

@end
```

I'm not sure how to get stack trace info (Xcode 4.2). Also, on analyze there are a couple of warnings, but nothing serious (eg. blue).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `self.scrollView = view` OR `scrollView = [view retain]` in your `initWithTableView:` method in `ProfileDateTableDelegate.m`.

Basically what is happening is that your scrollView is being released in some other view before you are able to access it since your "delegate" class does not retain it in any way, even though you have specified `nonatomic,retain` on your property.  Since you are setting the ivar directly in `init` instead of using the setter property, the retain is not being called on it.  When using the ivar directly, you must call `retain` yourself if you want it retained.

One way to avoid this error is to use an underscore `_` before or after your ivars (Apple uses before, so I use after to avoid private ivar collisions), like so:

in .h:

```
@interface{
    UIScrollView *scrollView_;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) UIScrollView *scrollView;
```

in *.m:

```
@synthesize scrollView = scrollView_;
```

Then, you in `init`, you can retain the view coming in like so:

```
scrollView_ = [view retain];
```

Just make sure you properly release it in `dealloc`:

```
- (void)dealloc{
    [scrollView_ release], scrollView_ = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

You can find more info about all this [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html).

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the dreaded`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. Without going through all your code, here's a tip that'll get you going right off the bat. Run the Analyzer. Then, use the Leaks tool in Instruments.

For details, along with the excellent link on what causes these errors and step by step instructions for how to fix, have a look at answers to these questions:

[finding reason for EXC_BAD_ACCESS - in Xcode4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477090/finding-reason-for-exc-bad-access-in-xcode4/8049630#8049630)

[Random EXC_BAD_ACCESS in a place that it cannot happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359111/random-exc-bad-access-in-a-place-that-it-cannot-happen/8049266#8049266)