# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with partialMockForObject and a UIView

Tags: exception, uiview, ocmock

I've got some troubles with OCMock and UIView.

I have sort of this code:

```
UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
id view1Mock = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:view1];

[[[view1Mock expect] andForwardToRealObject] removeFromSuperview];

... something ...

[view1Mock verify];
```

And I do get really often a EXC_BAD_ACCESS on [[[view1Mock expect] andForwardToRealObject] removeFromSuperview]. But not every time. It's quite annoying because I'cant track it down to the line on OCMock and it's not occurring every time.

Any idea?

EDIT:

I use the new Apple LLVM 3.0 Compiler with ARC enabled and i think that might be the reason. But I'd like to fix it. Has anyone tried to compile OCMock with ARC?

Best wishes,
Daniel

Comment: I'm getting the exact same problem. It only happens intermittently, and I'm just mocking a UIView like you are. The only difference is that I'm getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS when my application code attempts to add the mock object as a subview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As 'removeFromSurperview' is a UI method, maybe this could should be executed in main thread.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

The line where you *sometimes* receive a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` can be a clue as to problem cause. It's not certain though. The offending code might be elsewhere.

Certainly, your code above looks fine. As long as you are doing a `release` on `view1` at some point later.

UI operations must be run on the main thread. However, that won't cause the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` or any other explicit exception.

So, to find the root cause of the problem, the first step is to run the Analyzer. Then, use the Leaks tool in Instruments.

For details, along with the excellent link on what causes these errors and step by step instructions for how to fix them, have a look at answers to these questions:

[finding reason for EXC_BAD_ACCESS - in Xcode4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477090/finding-reason-for-exc-bad-access-in-xcode4/8049630#8049630)

[Random EXC_BAD_ACCESS in a place that it cannot happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359111/random-exc-bad-access-in-a-place-that-it-cannot-happen/8049266#8049266)