# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I scroll my view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, exc-bad-access

I have two views: the first one is a `UITableView` in plain style (created programmatically); the second one is a `UIScrollView` that contains an image and a `UITableView` in grouped style (also created programmatically).

When I navigate from the firstView -> secondView everything works fine. However if I come back to the `firstView` and then I try to navigate firstView ->secondView for the second time, I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

**UPDATE**

This is the code of the `UITableView` delegate in the `secondView`:

```
-
 (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    switch (section) {
        case 0: 

        //header - breve descrizione
        return 2;

        break;
    case 1: //mappa

        //header - mappa statica (immagine) - footer (indirizzo)
        return 3;

        break;
    case 2: //review

        //header - prima review
        return 2;

        break;
    default:
        return 0;

        break;


 }

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case 0: //case titolo (header)


    return HTABLE_DESCR_HEADER;
                    break;

                case 1: //case corpo
                    return HTABLE_DESCR_BODY;
                    break;

                default:
                    return 0;
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 1:

            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case 0: //case titolo (header)
                    return HTABLE_LOC_HEADER;
                    break;

                case 1: //case corpo
                    return HTABLE_LOC_BODY;
                    break;

                case 2: //case footer 
                    return HTABLE_LOC_FOOTER;
                    break;

                default:
                    return 0;
                    break;
            }

            break;
        case 2:

            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case 0: //case titolo (header)
                    return HTABLE_REV_HEADER;
                    break;

                case 1: //case corpo
                    return HTABLE_REV_BODY;
                    break;

                default:
                    return 0;
                    break;
            }

            break;
        default:            
            return 0;
            break;
    }

}

/*- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

 return @"Travellers Guide";

 }*/

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    int section = 2;

    //se ci sono review
    if ([[[[SingletonCardPOI sharedCardPOI] dicCard] objectForKey:@"list_review"] count] > 0) {
        section++;
    }

    return section;

}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [self getCellContentView:CellIdentifier];
    }    

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0: //descrizione

            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case 0: //header

                    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"language"] isEqualToString:@"it"]) {
                        cell.textLabel.text = @"Descrizione";
                    } else {
                        cell.textLabel.text = @"Description";
                    }
                    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                    cell.textLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                    cell.textLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
                    cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0];
                    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rigaDescrHeader.png"]];

                    break;

                case 1: //descrizione

                    NSLog(@"Descr");

                    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rigaRevBody.png"]];
                    cell.textLabel.text = [[[SingletonCardPOI sharedCardPOI] dicCard] objectForKey:@"description"];
                    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0];
                    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
                    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 3;
                    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                    cell.textLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                    cell.textLabel.shadowOffset =CGSizeMake(1, 1);
                    cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];

                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            break;
        case 1: //mappa

            //header - mappa statica (immagine) - footer (indirizzo)
            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case 0: //header

                    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"language"] isEqualToString:@"it"]) {
                        cell.textLabel.text = @"Posizione";
                    } else {
                        cell.textLabel.text = @"Location";
                    }
                    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0];
                    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                    cell.textLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                    cell.textLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
                    cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rigaLocHeader.png"]];

                    break;

                case 1: //mappa

                    NSLog(@"Mappa");

                    CLLocationDegrees latitude  = [[[[SingletonCardPOI sharedCardPOI] dicCard] objectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
                    CLLocationDegrees longitude = [[[[SingletonCardPOI sharedCardPOI] dicCard] objectForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];
                    CLLocation* poiLocation = [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude] autorelease];
                    Annotation *ann = [Annotation annotationWithCoordinate:poiLocation.coordinate];
                    //mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, HTABLE_LOC_BODY)];
                    [mapView setHidden:NO];
                    [mapView addAnnotation:ann];
                    MKCoordinateRegion region = {{0.0f, 0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}};
                    region.center = poiLocation.coordinate;                    
                    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.05f;
                    region.span.latitudeDelta  = 0.05f;
                    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
                    [self.mapView regionThatFits:region];
                    cell.backgroundView = mapView;


                    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 302, 120)]; 
                    imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ombraMappa.png"];
                    [cell.backgroundView addSubview:imgView];
                    [imgView release];

                    break;

                case 2: //footer

                    cell.textLabel.text = [[[SingletonCardPOI sharedCardPOI] dicCard] objectForKey:@"locality"];
                    cell.textLabel.font =[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0];
                    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                    cell.textLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                    cell.textLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
                    cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];

                    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[[SingletonCardPOI sharedCardPOI] dicCard] objectForKey:@"address"];
                    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:9.0];
                    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
                    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                    cell.detailTextLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                    cell.detailTextLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
                    cell.detailTextLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rigaLocFooter.png"]];

                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            break;
        case 2: //review

            //header - mappa statica (immagine) - footer (indirizzo)
            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case 0: //header

                    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"language"] isEqualToString:@"it"]) {
                        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Recensioni (%d)",[[[[SingletonCardPOI sharedCardPOI] dicCard] objectForKey:@"list_review"] count]];
                    } else {
                        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Review (%d)",[[[[SingletonCardPOI sharedCardPOI] dicCard] objectForKey:@"list_review"] count]];
                    }
                    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0];
                    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                    cell.textLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                    cell.textLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
                    cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];

                    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rigaLocHeader.png"]];

                    break;

                case 1: //review

                    cell.textLabel.text = [[[[[SingletonCardPOI sharedCardPOI] dicCard] objectForKey:@"list_review"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"review"];
                    cell.textLabel.font =[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0];
                    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
                    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 3;
                    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                    cell.textLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                    cell.textLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
                    cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rigaRevBody.png"]];

                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            break;
        default:                
            break;
    }

    return cell;

}


- (UITableViewCell *) getCellContentView:(NSString *)cellIdentifier {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Dany please search exc_bad_access.. or simply click any of the related links in the right column. There are ways to debug this (hint: zombies). I am sure you will be able to solve this issue yourself. Plus no one will be able to help without code.

Comment: We'll need to see your code, also are you using ARC?

Comment: Are u sending release to all objects, which were allocated? It seems you trying to get access to deallocated object..

Comment: It's not exec_bad_access; it's exc_bad_access (as in exception). I submitted an edit to correct this.

Comment: how about a stack trace? logs? any more hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` isn't caused by the progression of one view to the next. Rather, it will be properties of those views, or the creation and release - or not - of the view objects themselves that are to blame.

Your first step is to run the Analyzer. Then, if you've fixed all that and theres still a problem, start running the Leaks tool in Instruments.

For more details on resolving `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` issues, along with the excellent link on what causes these errors and step by step instructions for how to fix, have a look at answers to these questions:

[finding reason for EXC_BAD_ACCESS - in Xcode4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477090/finding-reason-for-exc-bad-access-in-xcode4/8049630#8049630)

[Random EXC_BAD_ACCESS in a place that it cannot happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359111/random-exc-bad-access-in-a-place-that-it-cannot-happen/8049266#8049266)

In your case, I'd specifically look at how you are creating `secondView`, and what you do with `firstView` when you return to `secondView`.

Comment: Why has this been edited with the wrong error message away from the correct one?

Comment: dunno. It's a common mistake. I've just fixed it.

Comment: Weirdness. And from a pretty big SO contributor.

Answer (score 1):

I just spent a week tracking down a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` problem in a large app that worked fine before converting it to ARC.  I would get the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on the closing bracket of a "switch" construct.  Yet `NSZombieEnabled` and the various Instrument settings would not detect anything for me.

What fixed it was putting curlies around the case's that made the difference.  I did it for each of them, though perhaps it was critical for only some, i.e.

Before:

```
case ...:
 stmt;
 stmt;
 break;
```

After:

```
case ...:{
 stmt;
 stmt;
 }break;
```

This fixed the problem in two places within a large app for me.  I know that I read something somewhere about ARC and switch/case (and maybe someone can add a link to it), but I don't understand the theory behind why this happened and why this fix worked.  Perhaps someone could explain. (Later: after reading the following reference at openradar, it all makes sense --- there is something wrong in the "cleanup code" generated between case statements --- a bogus "release" is generated and that soon causes the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.)

I also discovered this, which might be related:  http://openradar.appspot.com/11329693