# EXEC_BAD_ACCES on objective c class

Tags: objective-c, memory, exc-bad-access

I've created a small class which should be used to manage a SQLite database. But now, when I try to initialize the class and call a method - I get a EXEC_BAD_ACCES error. I've seen that this has something to do with memory management, right ? Maybe somebody can help me here or give me some advise ? Would be great!

See my sources:

Header File:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "FMDatabase.h"

@interface DatabaseManager : NSObject
{
    FMDatabase *database;
}

-(void)selectData;

@end
```

Implementation file:

```
#import "DatabaseManager.h"

@implementation DatabaseManager {

}

/*-------------------------------------------------------
* Class constructor
* Initializes the SQLite database connection.
-------------------------------------------------------*/
-(void)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {

        // Retrieve database path
        NSString* databasePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"database"     ofType:@"sqlite"];

        // Connect to database
        database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath: databasePath];

        // Check database connection
        if(![database open]) {
            database = nil;
            NSLog(@"ERROR: Failed to open SQLite connection!");
        }

    }
}


-(void)selectData: (NSString *)withSqlQuery{
    return withSqlQuery;
}

@end
```

Init of the class and call of the method:

```
DatabaseManager *databaseManager = [[DatabaseManager alloc] init];
[databaseManager selectData];
```

Best regards
ihkawiss

Comment: see thousands of existing posts on EXC_BAD_ACCESS, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232705/exc-bad-access-when-i-scroll-my-view/9277140#9277140

Comment: [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:] returns autoreleased object. Read about memory management in objective-c.

Answer (score 1):

```
    database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath: databasePath];
```

This returns an autoreleased object.  Unless you have ARC enabled (which you should), then that object will be released sometime in the near future; most likely at the end of the current pass through the run loop.

If you can't turn on ARC for some reason, `retain` that object.

And read about [Cocoa Memory Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html).